# Lyx - change URL appearance in bibtex bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, lyx, urls

**Problem**

I want the URLs displayed in my bibliography to have the same font, size and colour as the rest of my text. I am using the `natbib` citation management package and the `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style.

[image]

Furthermore I wondered if it is possible to change to complete font of the bibliography, as I like the else-harv referencing style I would like to only adapt it to my text font.

An example of my latex Code:

```
documentclass[11pt,twoside,english,openright, bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.75cm,rmargin=2.5cm,headheight=18pt,headsep=8pt,footskip=26pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{nomencl}
% the following is useful when we have the old nomencl.sty package
\providecommand{\printnomenclature}{\printglossary}
\providecommand{\makenomenclature}{\makeglossary}
\makenomenclature
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{lscape} 
{scrpage2} &oldpackage
\usepackage[automark, headsepline, footsepline, plainfootsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}
\ifoot[Test]{Test}
\cfoot[]{}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\ihead[]{}
\chead[]{}
\automark[chapter]{chapter} %rechte Seite erst dann Linke Seite
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\renewcommand\nomname{List of Acronyms}


\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=12pt,afterskip=12pt]{chapter}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\sffamily\LARGE}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=12pt,afterskip=10pt]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=12pt,afterskip=8pt]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-12pt,afterskip=8pt]{paragraph}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\sffamily\normalsize}

\usepackage {blindtext} 

\setkeys{Gin}{width=\textwidth} 
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[section]{placeins} 
\usepackage {media9} 
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=black,  citecolor=black]{hyperref} %gibt Bookmarks in bestimmter Farbe wieder

\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{_bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A separate comment: Since "Dijkstra" is the surname of a person, it shouldn't be lowercased even when it occurs in the `title` field of an entry. To keep BibTeX from converting `Dijkstra` to `dijkstra` -- as is done in the screenshot you posted -- encase it in a pair of curly braces, i.e., enter it in the `title` field as `... for {Dijkstra's} algorithm...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should add the instruction `\urlstyle{same}` to the preamble, immediately after loading the `url` package.

Second, you should change the option `urlcolor=blue` to `urlcolor=black` while loading the `hyperref` package.

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question, on how to insert a colon after the string `URL`. I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `elsarticle-harv.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make of a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `elsarticle-harv-colon.bst`. Do not edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.
- Open the file `elsarticle-harv-colon.bst` in a text editor. The one you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- Find the the string

  ```
  "\expandafter\ifx\csname urlprefix\endcsname\relax\def\urlprefix{URL }\fi"
  ```

  (It is located on line 1519 in my copy of the file.)
- In this line, change `\urlprefix{URL }` to `\urlprefix{URL: }`.
- Save the new bibliography style file either in the directory where you main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by your TeX distribution. If you choose the second option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv-colon}
  ```
- Rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

Comment: Is it also somehow possible to gete a colon after the URL in the bibliography ? And thanks for the first answer! :)

Comment: @KiW - You're welcome. I've posted an addendum to explain how to go about modifying the bibliography style file to get a colon after the string `URL`.

Comment: thanks for all the help, one last question - how can I include something after the URL like "Accessed: Date" ?

Comment: @KiW - Please post a *new query* to ask the *new question*. (Aside: The solution will require performing some not-insignificant surgery on the bst file.)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326761/add-output-types-to-misc-in-else-harv-bst-for-biblatex?noredirect=1#comment799533_326761 would be awesome if you could have a look at this! Would really appreciate some help!