# Include "Accessed at: Date" in bibtex else-harv bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, citing

**Problem**

Related to the question I asked here [Lyx - change URL appearance in bibtex bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326432/lyx-change-url-appearance-in-bibtex-bibliography/326461?noredirect=1#comment798537_326461), I would like to include something like "Accessed at: Date (dd.mm.yyyy)" in my bibliography. I am not 100 % sure "accessed at" is the right wording in english but this question is more focussed on how to implement this.

I am using Lyx with the Natbib setting and the else-harv biblipgraphy style.
I only want the accessed at date for all URLs that are displayed in the bibliography.
I have no clue how to start about it, apart from that probably something has to be changed in the .bst file ? Or is there some easiere solution to this.

What it should look like:

> URL: www.whatever.com (Accessed at: Date)

I am not sure about the style whether this is common with or without brackets around the accessed at, but I guess either will do.

**Code**

```
documentclass[11pt,twoside,english,openright, bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.75cm,rmargin=2.5cm,headheight=18pt,headsep=8pt,footskip=26pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{nomencl}
% the following is useful when we have the old nomencl.sty package
\providecommand{\printnomenclature}{\printglossary}
\providecommand{\makenomenclature}{\makeglossary}
\makenomenclature
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{lscape} 
{scrpage2} &oldpackage
\usepackage[automark, headsepline, footsepline, plainfootsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}
\ifoot[Test]{Test}
\cfoot[]{}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\ihead[]{}
\chead[]{}
\automark[chapter]{chapter} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\renewcommand\nomname{List of Acronyms}


\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=12pt,afterskip=12pt]{chapter}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\sffamily\LARGE}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=12pt,afterskip=10pt]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=12pt,afterskip=8pt]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-12pt,afterskip=8pt]{paragraph}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\sffamily\normalsize}

\usepackage {blindtext} 

\setkeys{Gin}{width=\textwidth} 
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[section]{placeins} 
\usepackage {media9} 
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=black, linkcolor=black,  citecolor=black]{hyperref} 

\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{_bib}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a patch file for the elsarticle-harv style:

```
--- /usr/share/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/elsarticle/elsarticle-harv.bst 2016-08-03 08:15:22.000000000 +0200
+++ elsarticle-harv.bst 2016-08-26 11:28:47.873108598 +0200
@@ -67,6 +67,7 @@
     title
     type
     url
+    urldate
     volume
     year
   }
@@ -368,7 +369,14 @@
 FUNCTION {write.url}
 { url empty$
     { skip$ }
-    { "\newline\urlprefix\url{" url * "}" * write$ newline$ }
+    {
+      "\newline\urlprefix\url{" url * "}" *
+      urldate empty$
+        'skip$
+        { " (Accessed at " * urldate * ")" * }
+      if$
+      write$ newline$
+    }
   if$
 }
```

Copy your `elsarticle-harv-bst` to your project and apply this patch. If you are on unix, save the patch in `patch.txt` and run

```sh
cp /usr/share/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/elsarticle/elsarticle-harv.bst . && patch < patch.txt
```

This patch extends the `write.url` function to include the date defined in the field `urldate`.

MWE:

`bib.bib`:

```
@article{key,
  author={foo},
  year={2016},
  url={http://example.com},
  urldate={2016-08-26}
}
```

`test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citet{key}

\bibliographystyle{my_elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am quite new to playing around with the .bst files so what exactly do you mean by appyling the patch? Do I copy in what you posted and if yes where abouts ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: the lines starting with `@@` separate different chunks of changes. After the `@@` are the line numbers where the changes start (in this case, 67 and 368). Then, every line preceded by a `-` is deleted in the original version, and you add every line starting with a `+`. (Lines without a `+` or `-` remain unchanged and are for context only.) — **edit**: on unix, you can use the `patch` command.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot - I will give it a try!

Comment: Just out of curiosity it looks like you can run that patch somehow, how would you do that ? EDIT: I am using Windows ;) ... I guess you just answered this one