# Bibtex Hack - Add output types to misc in else-harv.bst for bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, citing

I am using Windows, Lyx, Jabraf, Bibtex, else-harv.bst

**Adding fields to misc**

I would like to add output files to my else-harv.bst file for the type misc.
Namely I would like to include:

> Subtitle
>
> Institution
>
> Date

In the same order as the above stated, so that the output would be:

> Author, Title, Subtitle, Institution, Date, Howpublished

**Or even better:**

An even better solution to this problem would be to get bibtex to display all fields that are entered in Jabraf in the misc - type.

Have searched the forum a bit and I haven't found any solution to this, therefore help is very appreciated. Please note I am a noob-programmer, so I hope my question is even possible.

**Examplary Misc Entry**

```
@Misc{testmiscentry,
  author       = {Doe, John},
  title        = {This is a title}},
  subtitle     = {This is a subtitle},
  year         = {2016},
  date         = {2016-08-26},
  institution  = {Test Bank}
  howpublished = {Personal communication},
}
```

**Edit**

Since this question achieved quite little attention I would be also appreciative for not complete answers, but just for ways to start.

**A Latex Minimal Example**

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,british,openright, bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}

\citet{testmiscentry}

\bibliographystyle{C:/Users/[....]/else-harv.bst}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{test_bib}

\end{document}
```

Note that the bibliographystyle path is not complete. I have not included my whole Lyx exported Latex code, but I think these are the relevant things.

**Edit**

I managed to get the institution field included by adding

```
  institution "institution" output.check
```

in the misc function so that:

```
FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title output
  new.sentence
  institution "institution" output.check
  howpublished output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}
```

I can live without getting the subtitle to work, but I would really appreciate some help to get `date` added to the output.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. If you use `biblatex`, tradition .bst files are of no use to you, `biblatex` cannot handle them.

Comment: I am sorry I meant bibtex ( dont know what i was thinking there)

Comment: You can `edit` your question at the bottom left to correct it. You can help people to help you by providing a complete working minimal example. You'd need to include a sample `.bib` entry for this, of course. Not many people speak BST, so it will help to encourage those that do to try answering if they can. (Unlike Biblatex, BibTeX styles are written in a completely different language from TeX/LaTeX, which is why they are much more difficult to customise.) Improving your question is more likely to help get answers than a bounty, in my opinion. (Bounties do more for better questions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make several modifications to the bst file:

1) Add `date` and `subtitle` to `ENTRY`

```
ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    date
    edition
    editor
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    subtitle
    title
    type
    url
    volume
    year
  }
  {}
  { label extra.label sort.label short.list }
```

2) Define 2 new functions, `format.mydate` and `format.subtitle`

```
FUNCTION {format.mydate}
{ date empty$
    { "" }
    { date }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.subtitle}
{ subtitle empty$
    { "" }
    { subtitle "t" change.case$
    }
  if$
}
```

3) Modify function `misc`

```
FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title output
  format.subtitle output
  new.sentence
  institution output
  format.mydate output
  howpublished output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}
```

---

Besides note that your bib file is incorrect.  It should read:

```
@Misc{testmiscentry,
  author       = {Doe, John},
  title        = {This is a title},
  subtitle     = {This is a subtitle},
  year         = {2016},
  date         = {2016-08-26},
  institution  = {Test Bank},
  howpublished = {Personal communication}
}
```